# How to fix 422 status response from patch

Tags: java, spring-boot, axios, patch

I have a react front and java backend.  I am using a axios.patch request and I keep receiving a 422 response.  I do not know what is wrong.  I would like this to update correctly.  I'm using jsonpatch to try and update this object.

I've tried numerous things.  Is there something wrong with my request?  I do not know.

Here my code:

```
 return API.patch(`bmwsales/updateWeb/${vid}/`, veh, {headers: { 
'Authorization' : basic }})
             .then((response) =>{
                    if (response.status==200){
   dispatch(updateVehicleSuccess());
                    }

                }, (error) =>{
                        if (error.response.status == 500){

  dispatch(vehicleError(error.message, "Could not update rfidtag, please try again."));
                        }else if 
(error.response.status == 422){

dispatch(vehicleError(error.message, "Could not update rfidtag, please try again."));
                        }
```

controller:

```
@PatchMapping("/bmwsales/updateWeb/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateVehicleTagWeb(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id, @RequestBody Bmwsales v) throws JsonProcessingException{
    ObjectMapper objMapper=new ObjectMapper();
            JsonPatchBuilder jsonPatchBuilder=Json.createPatchBuilder();
    JsonPatch jsonPatch=jsonPatchBuilder.replace("/templocation",v.getTemplocation()).replace("/rfidtag", v.getRfidtag()).build();
    Bmwsales vehicle=bmwService.getVin(id).orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
BmwsalesUpdate veh=oMapper.asInput(vehicle);
    BmwsalesUpdate h=patchHelp.patch(jsonPatch, veh, BmwsalesUpdate.class);
    oMapper.INSTANCE.update(vehicle, h);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(h, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I would like to know how to fix this....

error:
xhr.js:178 PATCH http://...../bmwsales/updateWeb/69406/ 422

Looks like this is happening....there currently is no value in templocation and I'm trying to update it....how do I change my object mapper to accept that the current value can be null?  I'm thinking this is the problem...maybe...

javax.json.JsonException: '{"id":69406,"rfidtag":"E200420C71A06015010B6362"}' contains no value for name 'templocation'

OK I think I fixed this....I changed my Jackson Config to comment out the setdefaultpropertyinclusion to only include non null. Now that is ok.  But now instead of updating the 2 fields that I have indicated the json patch is trying to update the whole object. How do I restrict this?

Comment: You can simplify code a bit changing the param `Integer id` to `Bmwsales vehicle` (spring boot does some aspect-proxy-magic and then it maps that `id` to en `entity` or null). Maybe not to `Bmwsales` exact (if its DTO), but to an entity class

Comment: P.S. `(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id, ...` -> `(@PathVariable(value="id") YurEntityClass vehicle, ...`

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I need to have the id and the Bmwsales object separate.  The id is the id of the Bmwsales object I want to update.  Then the Bmwsales object coming over has the 2 items that I want to update.  @RostyslavBarmakov

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the `consumes` attribute inside the `@PatchMapping` with the value `APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in the class `MediaType` and the `value` field with the URL string, also check your `Bmwsales` object and see if all the fields matches with your request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The Bmwsales object has 35 fields.  I only need to update 2 of them so the Bmwsales object that is coming into my controller only have 2 fields that aren't null...is that an issue? @snake_404

Comment: Maybe, can you put your Bmwsales code here? Or just validate if your field doesn't have a `required` field or something like that. I guess you already did that but just in case, have you debugged your code and validate that you can reach the controller code?